# Why all the Icons of my custom bottom tab bar navigator are moving at the same time?

Tags: react-native, animation, react-navigation

I am trying to create a **CustomBottomTabNavigator** in react native. By now I have applied the linear gradient and added the icons on top of the tab. My goal is to move the **icon** upwards when the **focus** is on it, but for some reason, all the icons are moving upwards when the focus is on only one icon.

Here is the code:

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  Animated,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from "react-native";
import * as Icons from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { LinearGradient } from "expo-linear-gradient";

const CustomTabBar = ({ state, descriptors, navigation }) => {
  let icons_name = ["home", "search", "tv", "user"];
  const animatedValueHome = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

  const translateY = animatedValueHome.interpolate({
    inputRange: [50, 100, 150],
    outputRange: [25, 50, 75],
  });

  const animationHome = (focus, name) => {
    console.log("name", name);
    navigation.navigate(name);
    if (focus === true) {
      Animated.timing(animatedValueHome, {
        toValue: -25,
        duration: 1000,
        useNativeDriver: false,
      }).start();
    } else {
      Animated.timing(animatedValueHome, {
        toValue: 0,
        duration: 1000,
        useNativeDriver: false,
      }).start();
    }
  };

  return (
    <LinearGradient
      colors={["#181823", "#3A3A46", "#3A3A46"]}
      start={{ x: 0, y: 0.5 }}
      end={{ x: 1, y: 0.5 }}
      locations={[0.2, 0.6, 0.3]}
      style={styles.container}
    >
      <View style={styles.tabs}>
        {state.routes.map((route, index) => {
          const isFocused = state.index === index;
          return (
            <Animated.View
              key={index}
              style={{
                flex: 1,
                flexDirection: "row",
                transform: [{ translateY }],
              }}
            >
              <Icons.Feather
                name={icons_name[`${index}`]}
                size={24}
                color="#fff"
                onPress={() => animationHome(isFocused, route.name)}
              />
            </Animated.View>
          );
        })}
      </View>
    </LinearGradient>
  );
};

export default CustomTabBar;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    position: "absolute",
    height: 40,
    bottom: 20,
    right: 30,
    left: 20,
    elevation: 2,
    borderRadius: 20,
  },
  tabs: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    marginLeft: 48,
  },
});
```

Here is the gif of the animation that is happening
[Gif](https://media.giphy.com/media/oLckOiKBjTtJKtAKas/giphy.gif). I am using animated API from react-native to achieve this animation.

Comment: They all use `transform: [{ translateY }]`. The same translateY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let each of the child components have their own animation values.

```
// In the parent component
{state.routes.map((route, index) => {
  const isFocused = state.index === index;
  return <Child isFocused={isFocused} />;
})}

// Then for each child
const Child = ({ isFocused }) => {
  const animatedValueHome = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

  const translateY = animatedValueHome.interpolate({
    inputRange: [50, 100, 150],
    outputRange: [25, 50, 75],
  });

  const animationHome = (focus, name) => {
    console.log("name", name);
    navigation.navigate(name);
    if (focus === true) {
      Animated.timing(animatedValueHome, {
        toValue: -25,
        duration: 1000,
        useNativeDriver: false,
      }).start();
    } else {
      Animated.timing(animatedValueHome, {
        toValue: 0,
        duration: 1000,
        useNativeDriver: false,
      }).start();
    }
  };

return (
  <Animated.View
    style={{
      transform: [{ translateY }],
    }}
  >
    <Icons.Feather onPress={() => animationHome(isFocused, route.name)}/>
  </Animated.View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I was curious to know how the animation will automatically go up when the focus is on them because now the icons only go up when I click on them.

Comment: Then add an effect that calls your animation start when then focus prop updates.

Comment: useEffect (() => animationHome(is focused), [isFocused]);